# How To Get Random Number In HTML/Java Script And Have Something Different Happen With Each One

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to make a HTML file that will open a random picture out of 6. What I have already will only open the one the one that I specify. Is there a way to make it open a random one.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <body>
            <img src="IMG_1643.jpg" width="100%"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                setInterval("window.close()", 10000);
            </script>
        </body>
```

The names of the 6 images I have are:

```
^04CA0231DA52E6C51B485BD9D7B46A52692ECC1CCB4F6E30A4^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.jpg
^EE8BDA9E7F039326CF7340D2B4849A4ECA9E466F65BF7C4EE3^pimgpsh_fullsize_distr.jpg
IMG_1643.jpg
YTpic1 .png
YTpic2.jpg
YTpic2.gif
```

Comment: You want a random image only when people refresh or enter the page first time right?

Comment: yes, this page is going to open up for 10 seconds then close so I can display one of the 6 images at random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need: [JSfiddle - change img on reload](http://jsfiddle.net/hv50ky7L/).

In this example I'm using images from the internet but what you should do is to change the elements names on the array and everything will work fine. Example: change this "http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/22200000/-ZORO-one-piece-22288454-414-479.jpg" for this "YTpic2.gif".

This is the HTML code:

```
<img src="d" id="myImg"/>
```

This is the JavaScript code:

```
var images = [ "http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/22200000/-ZORO-one-piece-22288454-414-479.jpg", "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-VOiVpheXW_g/UmkqgPZFMZI/AAAAAAAAASU/0BF1y4ox4Bw/s1600/nico_robin_2y_by_deiviscc-d3jdk02.png", "http://www.renders-graphiques.fr/image/upload/normal/Zoro_calendrier_2013_by_Kakarot.png", "http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120302234410/onepiece/es/images/archive/9/90/20130106193654!Timeskip_Zoro.png", "http://st-listas.20minutos.es/images/2013-07/364756/4091397_640px.jpg?1373467101", "http://i615.photobucket.com/albums/tt232/Celtanor/Manga%20and%20Anime%20Renders/One%20Piece/RoronoaZoro17B.png"
];

(function () {
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = images[Math.ceil(Math.random() * images.length)-1];
})()
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Worked perfectly

Comment: @DragonHeart000 If it was i really apreciate if you could mark as correct answer my solution :). Wish you the best for the future.